# SQL filter to keep duplicate item

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hello I am wondering if this example can be done by SQL. If can't, please tell me.

Query result:

```
Id  | Qty |
A   |  1  |
B   |  3  |
B   |  5  |
C   |  2  |
C   |  1  |
C   |  4  |
```

Because Id B and C have row more than one in query result, I will keep them and remove Id A from result. So the result become:

```
Id  | Qty |
B   |  3  |
B   |  5  |
C   |  2  |
C   |  1  |
C   |  4  |
```

I have no clue to find this and tell me if cannot be done by SQL.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Please tag the **RDBMS** you are using, don't tag more than one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using SQL Server, one way is to use `COUNT OVER`:

```
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT *, 
        cnt = COUNT(Id) OVER(PARTITION BY Id)
    FROM tbl
)
SELECT
    Id, Qty
FROM CTE
WHERE cnt > 1
```

---

Use `COUNT` and `HAVING` for standard SQL

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl
WHERE 
    Id IN(
        SELECT Id
        FROM tbl
        GROUP BY Id
        HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

try this query

```
SELECT Id, Qty, COUNT(Id) 
FROM table
GROUP BY Id
HAVING ( COUNT(Id) > 1 );
```

Comment: Qty is not contained in aggregate..Check your query